# I having trouble installing tia portal v16 professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plc, siemens, tia-portal, ladder-logic

after I put 'next', it appears like this bellow.

x dummy.
I don't how to fix this error.

I tried install so many times but I still have this error.
I hope everyone help me fix this error.[image]

Comment: Go to folder %AUTINSTLOG%, and view the SIA install log file.  Check especially for Visual C++ redistributable errors.  Actually, I got this advice from here (you'll need to translate to english): https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/de/de/posts/tia-v16-installation-fehler-vorraussetzung-dummy/235761/?page=0&pageSize=10

Comment: I this a joke?  If not that is very funny.

Comment: If you are referring to the error message with the word "dummy", yes it's a thing as per the SIOS forum post above.  I suppose they forgot to add a description for this type of error in the installer.  The key thing is to check the install log.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to install the latest V16 version (update 6, https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/109775861/updates-for-step-7-v16-s7-plcsim-v16-and-wincc-v16?dti=0&lc=en-US)
- Also check the readme: https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/attachments/109775861/ReadMe_TIA_V16_UPD6_enUS.pdf
- Check the Windows Event Log for installation failures for the time when this error appears.